# Использование this в методах классов

Tags: c++

Есть вот такой код:

```
template<typename T>
struct somestruct
{
...

T somefunction(somestruct<T>* const th = this)
{
    return th ? th->somefield1 : this->somefield2;
}

...  
};
```

Компилятор VS 2017 ругается:

> Ошибка    C2355   "this": может указываться только в нестатических
>   членах-функциях или инициализаторах нестатических членов данных

Объясните пожалуйста, почему я не могу подобным образом использовать `this`?

Я хотел бы, чтобы вызов `somepointer->somefunction(otherpointer)` возвращал поле объекта указателя из аргумента, если он не `nullptr`, иначе возвращал другое поле объекта указателя, вызвавшего метод. А если `somefunction` вызывается без аргументов, то это было бы аналогично вызову `somepointer->somefunction(somepointer)`. Конечно, можно делать такой вызов явно или просто перегрузить `somefunction`, но интересно, почему нельзя так, как я написал.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Короткий ответ: потому что в стандарте языка сказано, что так нельзя.

Длинный ответ: в языке С++ не допускается формирование значений аргументов по умолчанию на основе параметров функции.

```
void foo(int a, int b, int c = a + b) // Ошибка
{
  ...
}
```

`this` - это тоже неявный параметр нестатического метода класса, поэтому использовать его для формирования значения аргумента по умолчанию не дозволяется. Причина этого заключается, в частности, в том, что это привело бы в необходимости вычислять параметры функции в некотором "правильном" порядке, а язык С++ не упорядочивает и никогда не упорядочивал вычисление параметров.<sup>†</sup> Это может быть не единственной причиной такого запрета.

Вместо аргумента по умолчанию вы можете просто использовать перегрузку и получить требуемый эффект

```
template<typename T>
struct somestruct
{
  ...

  T somefunction(somestruct<T>* const th)
  {
    return th ? th->somefield1 : this->somefield2;
  }

  T somefunction()
  {
    return somefunction(this);
  }

  ...  
};
```

---

<sup>†</sup> Начиная с С++17 вычисление аргумента для неявного параметра `this` *упорядочено перед* вычислением всех остальных аргументов. Теоретически, это должно было бы устранить вышеописанную проблему с порядком вычисления, но пока что это не привело к изменениям в спецификации использования `this` в аргументах по умолчанию.

Comment: Ааа, точно, я совсем упустил, что `this` это тоже аргумент функции. Это, конечно, грубый просчет. Спасибо за консультацию.

Comment: @AnT *"вычисление неявного параметра this упорядочено перед вычислением всех остальных аргументов"* Я правильно понимаю, что это означает, что в `a().b(c())` гарантируется, что `a()` вычисляется перед `c()`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Да, именно так. Параграф http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#8 и пример с `std::string` в нем посвящен как раз этой детали.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, причина заключается в том, что пока компилятор не увидел cv-квалификаторы на методе, тип `this` неизвестен (т.е. неизвестно, указатель это на константный класс или нет), и поэтому его запрещено использовать до cv-квалификаторов.

Пример:

```
struct A
{
    auto f1() const -> decltype(this) {return 0;} // Возвращает `const A *`.
    auto f2()       -> decltype(this) {return 0;} // Возвращает `A *`.

    decltype(this) f3() const {return 0;} // Ошибка компиляции, т.к. когда компилятор видит
    // `decltype(this)`, он еще не знает, константный ли это метод, и должен ли `this` быть
    // `A *` или `const A *`.

    decltype(this) f3()       {return 0;} // Ошибка компиляции, по той же причине.

    void foo(A * = this) {}; // Опять же, компилятор не знает, имеет ли `this` тип
    // `A *` или `const A *, поэтому просто не дает его использовать.
}
```